# Google Apps Script - Range Picker

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there an existing control or widget in Apps Script that will create a Range Picker, like in a ["Named ranges"](http://screencast.com/t/KyjfOeye84) sidebar?

Answer (score 0):

just highlight the range you want then call `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getActiveRange()`

Comment: I want to use something more userfriendly. And anyway, if I need several selected ranges from user at the same time? Range Picker is a common control in Excel, that's why I thought that Google provides something similar.